# Adapter for the RestClient?

Tags: c#, adapter, .net-core, restsharp, dotnet-httpclient

I am new to design patterns and I'm trying to write a *REST client library* using `.NET Standard` for a service that delivers *application/json*.
However, the `RestSharp` doesn't support `.NET Standard` *yet (there is an open issue on github)*.

To be able to use it in the future, and to adhere to “program to an interface, not an implementation” principle, I am going to create a public interface (`IRestClient`), which will encapsulate the needed functionality: the `Execute()` and `ExecuteAsync()` methods.
The constructor of the main class of my library will have two overloads:

1. First, accepting the `IRestClient` interface. The calling application will have to implement an adapter for it (even if it's using the `RestSharp` library).
2. Parameter-less (as a fallback) which will use the built-in `HttpClient`-based implementation.

What I'm struggling with is that each class has it's own dependencies on both of these methods (e.g. `RestClient` depends on `IRestRequest` and `IRestResponse`, and for `HttpClient` it's `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage`). These dependencies have other dependencies and so on.
Is there a way I can create a common interface for these methods without re-writing all the dependent interfaces?

Comment: HttpClient is available in .NET Core. Just add the `System.Net.Http` package. It already works with Json. What benefit do you expect from duplicating everything as an interface, then reimplementing it? What *actual* problem are you trying to solve by abstracting HttpClient?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The ability to use any _REST library/class_ with my library. I am just practicing design patterns, but now I am more inclined to believe there is no way to do what I want...

Comment: that's not a problem. That is an assumption, that you may have to change the client under your library, and do so without having to rewrite a lot of code. *Patterns* are solutions to specific problems, they can't be applied "just in case". The short definition of design patterns is `A solution to a *problem* in a *context*`.

Comment: Besides, what makes you think that the interface you create now for one library will wokr when you try to use another one? For example, HttpClient doesn't have blocking methods because the program doesn't have to block waiting for a response. Why use `Execute()` at all? And why `Execute`, you are only `Send`ing a request to another server

Comment: `RestClient` doesn't have a `Send` method. It has `Execute()` instead. But thanks, I think you are right that I was about to over-architect things ;)

Comment: @ssooqua that's my point exactly.  HTTP doesn't execute anything. Why use `Execute` when the actual operation is sending a request? That's just one thing that will be different in other libraries

Comment: The best time to create such an abstraction is when you try to add a second library. Only then will you be able to see what *is* an abstraction and what isn't.